# How to generate an array

Tags: python

I want to generate an array in python numpy based on equation; 1/x for x = 1,2,3,...10 and I wrote; But I wasn't getting any output, please help

```
def Number(x):
  for x in range (1,11):
    y = 1/x
return y
y = Number(10)
print y
```

Comment: `def Number(x): return [1/y for y in range(1,x)]`.

Comment: Reason about the code: you define a function, then iterate over a range and _reassign_ a variable to whatever the last value is. Then, it goes nowhere because `return` is de-dented so isn't part of the function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return an list, you need to actually make a list and append to it (or use a list comprehension). You just create a variable and assign to it. Instead do:

```
def Number(x):
    y = []
    for x in range (1,11):
        y.append(1./x)
    return y
y = Number(10)
print y
```

Now if you want to, you could use a list comprehension. This is a pythonic way to generate a list in a single line. It would look something like this.

```
def Number(x):
    y = [1./x for x in range(1,11)]
    return y
y = Number(10)
print y
```

Another way to do this is to use the map builtin, which is different in python 3, but you are using 2.7, so we are good.

```
def Number(x):
    y = map(lambda x: 1./x, range(1,11))
    return y
y = Number(10)
print y
```

The map function is applies the function to the specified list. In this case, I use an anonymous lambda function `lambda x:1./x` which is a simple way of writing a function with x as an argument and returns 1/x. The map function applies the lambda function to each element in the list.

Comment: Nice elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done as follow

```
def Number(n):
    return np.array([1/i for i in range(1, n)])
```

now you can do that

```
y = Number(10)
```